# Equivalent Objective-C code for Google Maps GMap2.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds)?

Tags: objective-c, api, google-maps, mapkit, geocoding

I'm familiar with the Google Maps API and I'm trying to learned the iOS MapKit library now.  I have an iPhone application which takes an input string and geocodes it using Google Maps geocoder service.  I also want to set an appropriate zoom level for the new map but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

After reading, [Determining zoom level from single LatLong in Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312517/determining-zoom-level-from-single-latlong-in-google-maps-api#917997)

My plan was to parse the JSON response from the Google Maps API and extract the ExtendedData field.

```
 "ExtendedData":{
     "LatLonBox":{
         "north":34.13919,
         "south":34.067018, 
         "east":-118.38971, 
         "west":-118.442796
     }
```

Then using that I would like to set the bounds of my map accordingly using the MapKit setRegion function.

I started laying out a function to do this, but I'm a little lost on the logic...

```
- (void) setMapZoomForLocation(CLLocationCoordinate2D location, double north, double south, double east, double west){

    // some fancy math here....

    // set map region
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = location;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    // set the span so that the map bounds are correct
    span.latitudeDelta = ???;
    span.longitudeDelta = ???;

    region.span = span;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Alternatively, I guess I could just used the Accuracy result from a geocode result to set a sort of default zoom level.  I'm just not sure how to compute the equivalent default zoom levels for the various results.

See https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/#GeocodingAccuracy

------------------------ Update: Solution I Used ------------------------------

```
// parse json result
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSArray *placemarks = (NSArray *) [results objectForKey:@"Placemark"];
NSDictionary *firstPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

// parse out location
NSDictionary *point = (NSDictionary *) [firstPlacemark objectForKey:@"Point"];
NSArray *coordinates = (NSArray *) [point objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = [[coordinates objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
location.longitude = [[coordinates objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
// DEBUG
//NSLog(@"Parsed Location: (%g,%g)", location.latitude, location.longitude);

// parse out suggested bounding box
NSDictionary *extendedData = (NSDictionary *) [firstPlacemark objectForKey:@"ExtendedData"];
NSDictionary *latLngBox = (NSDictionary *) [extendedData objectForKey:@"LatLonBox"];

double north = [[latLngBox objectForKey:@"north"] doubleValue];
double south = [[latLngBox objectForKey:@"south"] doubleValue];
double east = [[latLngBox objectForKey:@"east"] doubleValue];
double west = [[latLngBox objectForKey:@"west"] doubleValue];
// DEBUG
//NSLog(@"Parsed Bounding Box: ne = (%g,%g), sw = (%g,%g)", north, east, south, west);

MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(fabs(north - south), fabs(east - west));
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is generate a MKCoordinateRegion, you shouldn't need to know anything at all about zoom level. Just create a coordinate region using the width and height of the LatLonBox.

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(fabs(north - south), fabs(east - west));
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Comment: That code seems to produce an invalid region for the following variables.  Location: (-93.6256,42.0234) and Bounding Box: ne = (42.0565,-93.5616), sw = (41.9902,-93.6897).  I get an 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:-93.62562200, +42.02335000 span:+0.06631170, +0.12805940>'
Any suggestions?