# Determine scale in meters per pixel

Tags: google-maps

Using google static maps, a 512x512 image is retrieved with center at a given latitude and longitude and at a given zoom level. Now How to find the meters per pixel for this image?

PS: I need to do this without javascript. Some kind of formula which can give the map scale (meters per pixel) based on zoomlevel, latitude, longitude will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See the stackoverflow question [*"Determining zoom level from single LatLong in Google Maps API"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312517/determining-zoom-level-from-single-latlong-in-google-maps-api) to get the latitude/longitude box around your results. Then, see the stackoverflow question [*"How to convert latitude or longitude to meters?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters) for the issues you will need to take into account.