# Setting perfect zoom level for a Place with Google API

Tags: google-maps

In my Google Maps app the user can search for a place (using Autocomplete) and the map will be re-centered upon it with `map.setCenter(pos);`.

This does not change zoom level though, that must be done manually with `map.setZoom(x)`.

In Google's map, zoom automatically readjusts to perfectly show the place's boundaries, how can I replicate that behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining zoom level from single LatLong in Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312517/determining-zoom-level-from-single-latlong-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: Hey that's exactly it, thank you!

edit: after looking it over and checking the google api, it appears that undocumented info has changed an is no longer available, so this question is not a duplicate :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The duplicate @woelliJ found almost worked, but ended up using an old version of the API. It led me on the right track though, and I ended up finding how to make it work with the new API - `map.fitBounds(autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.viewport);`